# D3 inserting a chart within the tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to insert a pie chart within a tooltip (not sure if it is possible though...) and ended up with the following code:

```
    var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(
        function(d) { if (d.company == "A" || d.company == "B") {
           return "Company: <span style='color:#ccff33'>"  + d.company+ " </span>"; 
        }

            else {

            var data = [60,40];
            var r = 100;

            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["blue", "orangered"]);

            var base = d3.select(this)

            var svg = base.append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500);

            var group = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(30, 30)");

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(10)
            .outerRadius(r);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .value(function (d) { return d;});

            var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            arcs.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data); })



            }
        }



  );

 baseSvg.call(tip);
```

The first codition with the text works fine, but the Else part that should draw the pie chart does not return anything, i have struggling for a couple of days. I think my mistake come from the select part, but can't figure it out.
I need the pie chart to pop up within the tooltip.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but the Else part that should draw the pie chart does not return anything"

That's exactly why it fails, the function returns null which then clears the tooltip's html attribute, overwriting what you've just carefully placed inside the tip.

try this at the end of your code:

```
return base.html();
```

that's everything you've just put in the tooltip turned into an html string, which the tooltip will then copy over the existing (and same) html.

Comment: Excellent! thanks. Another question if i may, the tooltip shows on and off when hovering the mouse as expected, but the pie charts are stacking up. Like the first time there is 1 chart, then the second time i hover my mouse, there are 2 charts, then 3 and so on...

Comment: You're appending new svg and g elements each time the tooltip is rendered. Probably the easiest way is just to blank the tooltip at the start of the else  condition before you add stuff --> `base.html(null)`