# D3 Inserting 2 SVG / charts within a tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is related to this question: 
[D3 inserting a chart within the tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300349/d3-inserting-a-chart-within-the-tooltip)
Where @mgraham helped me a lot solving my problem and insert a pie chart within a tooltip.

[image]

Now i am trying to insert a second pie chart in the same tooltip using different data (in front of budget), i came up with this code:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(
        function(d) { if (d.company == "A" || d.company == "B") {
        if (d.name == "C") {return "<?PHP echo $compListA."<br/>".$compListB; ?>";} 
          else {return "Competitors: <span style='color:#ccff33'>"  + d.competitors + " </span><BR/> Products/Services: <span style='color:#ccff33'>" + d.nbProducts + " </span><BR/> Segment Revenue (Co.): <span style='color:#ccff33'>$" + d.compSegRev + " M </span>  <BR/> Segment Revenue (Total): <span style='color:#ccff33'>$" + d.totSegRev +" M </span> "; 
         }
    }
        else { if (d.name == "C") {return "<?PHP echo $compListA."<br/>".$compListB; ?>";}

            else {


        //First Pie Chart
        var data = [d.salesA, d.salesB];
        var r = 10;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#33abf9", "orangered"]);

        var base = d3.select(this)

        base.html(null) ;

        var svg = base.append("svg")
            .attr("width", 20)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("id", "pie-1");

        var group = svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(r);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function (d) { return d;});

        var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data); });


    //Second PieChart       
        var data2 = [d.BudgetA, d.BudgetB];
        var r2 = 10;

        var color2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#33abf9", "orangered"]);

        var base2 = d3.select(this)

        base2.html(null)    ;

        var svg2 = base2.append("svg")
            .attr("width", 20)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("id", "pie-2");

        var group2 = svg2.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

        var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(r2);

        var pie2 = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function (d) { return d;});

        var arcs2 = group2.selectAll(".arc2")
            .data(pie2(data2))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc2");

        arcs2.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color2(d.data2); });

        return "Employees: <span style='color:#ccff33'>"  + d.nbEmployees+ " </span><BR/> Clients: <span style='color:#ccff33'>" + d.nbClients+ " </span> &nbsp;<BR/> Sales: <span style='color:#ccff33'>$" + d.TotSales + " M </span> &nbsp; " 
        + base.html()
        + "<BR/> Budget: <span style='color:#ccff33'>$" + d.totBudget+" M </span> "
        + base2.html(); 

            }



        }

    }
)   




baseSvg.call(tip);
```

2 charts do show in the tip but showing the same wrong colors/angles like they are mixed up.
I can't use closures in between as i used data from previous piece in the code.

Any help is highly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised 2 pies show up as it looks like you `base2.html(null)` after building the first pie which I'd have thought would have wiped the first one away...

Anyways I think your colours are wrong because you're accessing the color scale like this -->

```
arcs.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data); });
```

d.data doesn't exist and wouldn't map to a 2-element colour domain if it did, so if you want to distinguish the chunks do it by index, which should be like this

```
arcs.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); });
```

In the long run, if you collate your data into a nested array and do like in this fiddle, you won't need to build each svg individually either -->

https://jsfiddle.net/6d65yn7w/3/

Comment: thanks @mgraham. I see. i implemented the code from the fiddle (thanks a lot!) and i see now the 2 pies with correct angles and colors. But if i understand that piece of code correctly, the 2 pies get returned both at the same time together. Is there a way to retrieve them separately as the result i need is something like: [code] return "piece of text" + PIE1 + "<br> piece of text" + PIE2 ; [code] ?

Comment: You'd have to step outside d3 a little bit as `.html()` on the svg elements wouldn't return the enclosing svg tag. Do `var s = []; base.selectAll("svg").each(function() { s.push(this.outerHTML()); }` - this will store all the svg html strings including the svg tag in an array you can then add in to your returned string as s[0] etc

Comment: Once again, problem solved. i had to remove the double parenthesis after `outerHTML ` though as i had an error like outerHTML is not a function, so i have to use: `var s = []; base.selectAll("svg").each(function() { s.push(this.outerHTML); } ) `
 Thanks a lot  @mgraham for your clear and detailed explanation. I have to deliver something while still learning d3 from scratch, your help is very useful.